# ASP.NET httpHandlers & handlers

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am confused about httpHandlers in `system.web` and handlers in `system.webServer`. What is the difference between these two configuration? And how and when to use them?

Actually another question is for modules as well: httpModules in `system.web` and modules in `system.webServer`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The system.webServer section in the Web.config file specifies settings for IIS 7.0 that are applied to the Web application. The system.WebServer is a child of the configuration section. For more information, see IIS 7.0: system.webServer Section Group (IIS Settings Schema).

and `<system.web>` specifies the root element for the ASP.NET configuration section and contains configuration elements that configure ASP.NET Web applications and control how the applications behave. `httpHandlers` & `handlers` are same.

To register an HTTP handler for IIS 6.0 use should:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="SampleHandler.new" 
        type="SampleHandler, SampleHandlerAssembly" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

To register an HTTP handler for IIS 7.0 use should:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="SampleHandler.new" 
        type="SampleHandler, SampleHandlerAssembly" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <add name=SampleHandler" verb="*" path="SampleHandler.new" 
      Modules="IsapiModule" 
      scriptProcessor="FrameworkPath\aspnet_isapi.dll"
      resourceType="File" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Read more [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

Comment: Your IIS 7 example uses Classic mode, while modern apps use Integrated mode. The article describes it.

Answer (score 3):

`<system.web>` is the configuration section for asp.net, traditionally this is where you would define your httpHandlers and httpModules.

With the introduction of IIS 7 (2007) the web server and asp.net got much more integrated and a completely new IIS configuration system was introduced.

As part of this the location for handler and module definitions was moved to `<system.webServer>`

If you are still using IIS6 (stop it) or use classic pipeline mode in IIS7+ you need to have your definitions under `<system.web>`, if you are using integrated pipeline mode in IIS7+ put them under `<system.webServer>`. You should not have them in both sections.